# Include multiple subfolders without known root folder using single glob pattern

Tags: yaml, glob

I'm having a build drop of a complex solution that has a structure like this:

```
src/
  X/
  Y/
    A/
    B/
      C/
```

what means multiple projects on multiple levels.

I want to combine all their build output using single glob pattern:

```yaml
- from: '**\bin\Release\net462\win10-x64\'
  to: 'out\'
  include:
    - '**\*'
```

But it collects nothing. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently `from` must be a relative path, *not* a glob pattern. But `include` and `exclude` *can*:

```yaml
- from: 'src\'
  include:
    - '**\bin\x64\Release\**\'
  to: 'out\'
```